# Pass down function from parent component to child component is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function is not triggering. I checked many other answers and it seems like my code should be working.

In App parent component:

```
update() {
  console.log("hello");
}

<PrivateRoute
  exact
  path="/profile"
  component={Profile}
  update={this.update}
/>
```

In Profile child component:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={this.props.update}
>
```

Comment: Please show all relevant components, not just snippets.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in `PrivateRoute` you are not passing `update` method to `Profile` component.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path: Path, ...rest }) => (
//...rest of your code

         //pass update prop along with other props which are needed.
          <Component update={rest.update} /> 

//...rest of your code
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: THIS! Thank you! :)